# How to use smartphone camera with OpenCV (via USB) - Python

Tags: python, iphone, opencv

I am trying to use my iPhone camera with OpenCV. However, Python doesn't recognize the camera.
Some months ago I did it simply writing:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?
I know that there are other solutions like using IP address to use the camera with OpenCV, but I want to use the camera via USB.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, your way of accessing the camera of your iPhone is not supported by OpenCV, but there are other ways to implement OpenCV on iOS.

OpenCV Documentation tells you to
*add a camera controller to the view controller and initialize it when the view has loaded*.

This is done using an XCode project utilizing the OpenCV Framework, more information can be found here: [OpenCV iOS - Video Processing](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/dc8/tutorial_video_processing.html).